# Dynamic <select><option> with conditional <optgroup> as ng-container not working

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-template

I have created a small dropdown component which takes the following interface as `<option>`s:

```
interface DropdownSelectChoice {
    label: string;
    key: string;
}
```

The component to accepts a one- or two-dimensional array of choices

```
@Input() choices: DropdownSelectChoice[] | DropdownSelectChoice[][];
```

and if a two-dimensional array of choices is passed, to create unlabelled `<optgroup>`s of each set of choices:

```
<span [class.disabled]="disabled">
    <select (ngModelChange)="choose($event)"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [(ngModel)]="defaultChoice">

        <ng-container *ngIf="choices[0].constructor === Array">
            <optgroup *ngFor="let group of choices" [label]="null">
                <option *ngFor="let choice of group"
                        [value]="choice.key">
                    {{ choice.label }}
                </option>
            </optgroup>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="choices[0].constructor !== Array">
            <option *ngFor="let choice of choices"
                    [value]="choice.key">
                {{ choice.label }}
            </option>
        </ng-container>

    </select>
</span>
```

If I pass it a one-dimensional array, it works as expected:

```
choices: DropdownSelectChoice[] = [
    {
        label: "One",
        key: "1"
    },
    {
        label: "Two",
        key: "2"
    }
];
```

If I pass it a two-dimensional array:

```
choicesGroup: DropdownSelectChoice[][] = [
    [

        {
            label: "One",
            key: "1"
        },
        {
            label: "Two",
            key: "2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            label: "Three",
            key: "3"
        },
        {
            label: "Four",
            key: "4"
        }
    ]
];
```

I get `choicesGroup.length` blank `<option>`s with no `<optgroup>`.

Setting a break-point in the drop down component's initialiser, I confirm that `this.choices[0].constructor === Array` is `true` when passing `choicesGroup`, but the template seems always to be evaluating the `!== Array` template path.

What silly thing have I omitted that I am not noticing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types can't be used this way in templates.

Try

```
<ng-container *ngIf="choices[0].isArray">
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!choices[0].isArray">
```

if you still want to use `constructor === Array` you need to create a method and do the comparison there.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isArray(choices[0])">
```

```
isArray(obj) {
  return obj.constructor === Array;
}
```

Comment: I knew you'd have an answer! I guessed I had tried to access something disallowed in templates. I got the same (broken) behaviour with `choices[0].isArray` within the template, so I instead placed the original check in `ngOnInit` and stored that state to an additional class member boolean to simplify the template.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness -- informed by Günter's accepted answer, these are my final changes:

```
private grouped: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    this.grouped = this.choices[0].constructor === Array;
}
```

And in the template, I changed the ng-container's conditions to:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="grouped">...</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!grouped">...</ng-container>
```